# DRF - URL kwargs - get list in object

Tags: django, url, django-rest-framework, django-views, routes

I have this kind of url:

```
/store/<pk>/categories
```

I believe it's self-explanatory what it does. In terms of DB relation, Category has a foreign key to Store.

I do have a functioning code, but I think there must be a better or more proper way of implementing it. I just want to understand how DRF is meant to be used in this case.

```
class CategoriesListView(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer

    # TODO: is that right way of doing this?
    #       or there is some sort of lookup parameter that does the same?
    def get_queryset(self):
        store = get_object_or_404(Store, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return store.categories
```

Comment: IMO it looks ok. And you can also filter through `Categories`, like `Category.objects.filter(store=store_obj)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the best way to do it:

```
class CategoriesListView(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        pk = self.kwargs.get(self.lookup_field)
        store = get_object_or_404(Store, pk=pk)
        return store.categories.all()
```